# Is good practice to use exceptions for logic?

Tags: exception

I've got this example:

```
try {
    images = this.getFinderFiles(path);
} catch (DirectoryNotFoundException exception) {
    return [];
}
```

There is something wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not to use exception handling for expected error situations. Exception handling takes time, stack unwinding has to be done.
In your case, if you usually can expect that 'path' usually exists and therefore the method can return a decent result - so you do not expect that 'this.getFinderFiles' fails - then it is fine to use exceptions here. But otherwise test the path for existence first before calling 'getFinderFiles'. That should be faster and for my taste more readable.
Btw. can you check the existence of 'path' within 'getFinderFiles' and eventually return '[]' already there?